# How to do a cross join / cartesian product in RavenDB?

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

I have a web application that uses RavenDB on the backend and allows the user to keep track of inventory. The three entities in my domain are:

```
public class Location
{
    string Id
    string Name 
}

public class ItemType
{
    string Id
    string Name
}

public class Item
{
    string Id
    DenormalizedRef<Location> Location
    DenormalizedRef<ItemType> ItemType
}
```

On my web app, there is a page for the user to see a summary breakdown of the inventory they have at the various locations. Specifically, it shows the location name, item type name, and then a count of items.

The first approach I took was a map/reduce index on InventoryItems:

```
this.Map = inventoryItems =>
    from inventoryItem in inventoryItems
    select new
    {
        LocationName = inventoryItem.Location.Name,
        ItemTypeName = inventoryItem.ItemType.Name,
        Count = 1
    });

this.Reduce = indexEntries =>
    from indexEntry in indexEntries
    group indexEntry by new
    {
        indexEntry.LocationName,
        indexEntry.ItemTypeName,
    } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.LocationName,
        g.Key.ItemTypeName,
        Count = g.Sum(entry => entry.Count),
    };
```

That is working fine but it only displays rows for Location/ItemType pairs that have a non-zero count of items. I need to have it show *all* Locations and for each location, all item types even those that don't have any items associated with them.

I've tried a few different approaches but no success so far. My thought was to turn the above into a Multi-Map/Reduce index and just add another map that would give me the cartesian product of Locations and ItemTypes but with a Count of 0. Then I could feed that into the reduce and would always have a record for every location/itemtype pair.

```
this.AddMap<object>(docs =>
    from itemType in docs.WhereEntityIs<ItemType>("ItemTypes")
    from location in docs.WhereEntityIs<Location>("Locations")
    select new
    {
        LocationName = location.Name,
        ItemTypeName = itemType.Name,
        Count = 0
    });
```

This isn't working though so I'm thinking RavenDB doesn't like this kind of mapping. Is there a way to get a cross join / cartesian product from RavenDB? Alternatively, any other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

EDIT: To clarify, Locations, ItemTypes, and Items are documents in the system that the user of the app creates. Without any Items in the system, if the user enters three Locations "London", "Paris", and "Berlin" along with two ItemTypes "Desktop" and "Laptop", the expected result is that when they look at the inventory summary, they see a table like so:

```
| Location | Item Type | Count |
|----------|-----------|-------|
| London   | Desktop   | 0     |
| London   | Laptop    | 0     |
| Paris    | Desktop   | 0     |
| Paris    | Laptop    | 0     |
| Berlin   | Desktop   | 0     |
| Berlin   | Laptop    | 0     |
```

Comment: The problem is that what you want is _all_ the locations crossed with all the types, right?
The problem is that we can give you it by location or by type, but to combine them would cause issues. Can you do it first by location, then by type?

Comment: @AyendeRahien You are correct that I need all locations crossed with all types. The request came in because the end user can't see what items they're "out of stock" at a particular location. I've been reading more on the RavenDB Google Group and have seen some talk about Cartesian products not really being supported due to the "Safe by Default" mentality. In my case, we're talking tens of locations and maybe a thousand different types so the number of index entries isn't ridiculous. I'm not sure what you mean by "do it first by location then by type".

Comment: @DavidArcher I'm having somewhat the same challenge. Did you ever solve this? If so, could you be so kind as to provide the final index.

Comment: @FrederikStruck-Schøning Yes, I solved this by switching to SQL Server since RavenDB could not meet the requirement. Lesson learned.

Comment: @DavidArcher Ouch! I'm facing the somewhat same thing over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614013/ravendb-how-can-i-properly-index-a-cartesian-product-in-a-map-reduce - Moving away from RavenDB is not an option for us, so I think I might have to go with a more pragmatic solution. RavenDB is, afterall, not a relational database, and although it can do some cool stuff, you can't just JOIN like crazy :) Thanks for getting back.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this with all the empty locations as well:

```
AddMap<InventoryItem>(inventoryItems =>
    from inventoryItem in inventoryItems
    select new
    {
        LocationName = inventoryItem.Location.Name,
        Items = new[]{
            {
                ItemTypeName = inventoryItem.ItemType.Name,
                Count = 1}
            }
    });
)

this.AddMap<Location>(locations=>
    from location in locations
    select new
    {
        LocationName = location.Name,
        Items = new object[0]
    });


this.Reduce = results => 
    from result in results
    group result by result.LocationName into g
    select new
    {
        LocationName = g.Key,
        Items = from item in g.SelectMany(x=>x.Items)
                group item by item.ItemTypeName into gi
                select new
                {
                    ItemTypeName = gi.Key,
                    Count = gi.Sum(x=>x.Count)
                }

    };
```

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem. I edited the original question to add a more explicit example but basically I need to have results even when there are no InventoryItem documents in the system at all. If the user just creates some Locations and ItemTypes and hasn't entered any actual InventoryItems, the first map on the index you posted won't provide any results and the second will just give me one record per location.