# RavenDB: How can I properly index a cartesian product in a map-reduce?

Tags: ravendb, cartesian-product, cross-join

This question is a spin-off of [RavenDB: Why do I get null-values for fields in this multi-map/reduce index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559770/ravendb-why-do-i-get-null-values-for-fields-in-this-multi-map-reduce-index), but I realized, the problem was another.

Consider my extremely simplified domain, rewritten to a movie rental store scenario for abstraction:

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class MovieRental
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string MovieId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

It's a text-book many-to-many example.

The index I want to create is this:

> For a given user, give me a list of every movie in the database (filtering/search left out for the moment) along with an integer describing how many times (or zero) the user has rented this movie.

Basically like this:

**Users:**

```
| Id     |
|--------|
| John   |
| Lizzie |
| Albert |
```

**Movies:**

```
| Id           |
|--------------|
| Robocop      |
| Notting Hill |
| Inception    |
```

**MovieRentals:**

```
| Id        | UserId | MovieId      |
|-----------|--------|--------------|
| rental-00 | John   | Robocop      |
| rental-01 | John   | Notting Hill |
| rental-02 | John   | Notting Hill |
| rental-03 | Lizzie | Robocop      |
| rental-04 | Lizzie | Robocop      |
| rental-05 | Lizzie | Inception    |
```

Ideally, I want an index to query, that would look like this:

```
| UserId | MovieId      | RentalCount |
|--------|--------------|-------------|
| John   | Robocop      | 1           |
| John   | Notting Hill | 2           |
| John   | Inception    | 0           |
| Lizzie | Robocop      | 2           |
| Lizzie | Notting Hill | 0           |
| Lizzie | Inception    | 1           |
| Albert | Robocop      | 0           |
| Albert | Notting Hill | 0           |
| Albert | Inception    | 0           |
```

Or declaratively:

- I always want a full list of all the movies (eventually I will add filtering/searching) - even when providing a user that has never rented a single movie yet
- I want a count of the rentals for each user, just the integer
- I want to be able to sort by the rental-count - i.e. show the most-rented movies for a given user at the top of the list

However, I can't find a way to make the "cross-join" above and save it in the index. Instead, I initially thought I got it right with this maneuver below, but it does not allow me to sort (see failing test):

> {"Not supported computation: x.UserRentalCounts.SingleOrDefault(rentalCount => (rentalCount.UserId == value(UnitTestProject2.MovieRentalTests+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).user_john.Id)).Count. You cannot use computation in RavenDB queries (only simple member expressions are allowed)."}

My question is basically: **how can I - or can I at all - index so, that my requirements are fulfilled?**

---

Below is my mentioned example, that does not fulfill my requirements, but that's where I am right now. It uses the following packages (VS2015):

**packages.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="RavenDB.Client" version="3.5.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="RavenDB.Database" version="3.5.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="RavenDB.Tests.Helpers" version="3.5.2" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

**MovieRentalTests.cs**

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Raven.Client.Indexes;
using Raven.Client.Linq;
using Raven.Tests.Helpers;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MovieRentalTests : RavenTestBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void DoSomeTests()
        {
            using (var server = GetNewServer())
            using (var store = NewRemoteDocumentStore(ravenDbServer: server))
            {
                //Test-data
                var user_john = new User { Id = "John" };
                var user_lizzie = new User { Id = "Lizzie" };
                var user_albert = new User { Id = "Albert" };


                var movie_robocop = new Movie { Id = "Robocop" };
                var movie_nottingHill = new Movie { Id = "Notting Hill" };
                var movie_inception = new Movie { Id = "Inception" };

                var rentals = new List<MovieRental>
                {
                    new MovieRental {Id = "rental-00", UserId = user_john.Id, MovieId = movie_robocop.Id},
                    new MovieRental {Id = "rental-01", UserId = user_john.Id, MovieId = movie_nottingHill.Id},
                    new MovieRental {Id = "rental-02", UserId = user_john.Id, MovieId = movie_nottingHill.Id},
                    new MovieRental {Id = "rental-03", UserId = user_lizzie.Id, MovieId = movie_robocop.Id},
                    new MovieRental {Id = "rental-04", UserId = user_lizzie.Id, MovieId = movie_robocop.Id},
                    new MovieRental {Id = "rental-05", UserId = user_lizzie.Id, MovieId = movie_inception.Id}
                };

                //Init index
                new Movies_WithRentalsByUsersCount().Execute(store);

                //Insert test-data in db
                using (var session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    session.Store(user_john);
                    session.Store(user_lizzie);
                    session.Store(user_albert);

                    session.Store(movie_robocop);
                    session.Store(movie_nottingHill);
                    session.Store(movie_inception);

                    foreach (var rental in rentals)
                    {
                        session.Store(rental);
                    }

                    session.SaveChanges();

                    WaitForAllRequestsToComplete(server);
                    WaitForIndexing(store);
                }

                //Test of correct rental-counts for users
                using (var session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    var allMoviesWithRentalCounts =
                        session.Query<Movies_WithRentalsByUsersCount.ReducedResult, Movies_WithRentalsByUsersCount>()
                            .ToList();

                    var robocopWithRentalsCounts = allMoviesWithRentalCounts.Single(m => m.MovieId == movie_robocop.Id);
                    Assert.AreEqual(1, robocopWithRentalsCounts.UserRentalCounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user_john.Id)?.Count ?? 0);
                    Assert.AreEqual(2, robocopWithRentalsCounts.UserRentalCounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user_lizzie.Id)?.Count ?? 0);
                    Assert.AreEqual(0, robocopWithRentalsCounts.UserRentalCounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user_albert.Id)?.Count ?? 0);

                    var nottingHillWithRentalsCounts = allMoviesWithRentalCounts.Single(m => m.MovieId == movie_nottingHill.Id);
                    Assert.AreEqual(2, nottingHillWithRentalsCounts.UserRentalCounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user_john.Id)?.Count ?? 0);
                    Assert.AreEqual(0, nottingHillWithRentalsCounts.UserRentalCounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user_lizzie.Id)?.Count ?? 0);
                    Assert.AreEqual(0, nottingHillWithRentalsCounts.UserRentalCounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user_albert.Id)?.Count ?? 0);
                }

                // Test that you for a given user can sort the movies by view-count
                using (var session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    var allMoviesWithRentalCounts =
                        session.Query<Movies_WithRentalsByUsersCount.ReducedResult, Movies_WithRentalsByUsersCount>()
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.UserRentalCounts.SingleOrDefault(rentalCount => rentalCount.UserId == user_john.Id).Count)
                            .ToList();

                    Assert.AreEqual(movie_nottingHill.Id, allMoviesWithRentalCounts[0].MovieId);
                    Assert.AreEqual(movie_robocop.Id, allMoviesWithRentalCounts[1].MovieId);
                    Assert.AreEqual(movie_inception.Id, allMoviesWithRentalCounts[2].MovieId);
                }
            }
        }

        public class Movies_WithRentalsByUsersCount :
            AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<Movies_WithRentalsByUsersCount.ReducedResult>
        {
            public Movies_WithRentalsByUsersCount()
            {
                AddMap<MovieRental>(rentals =>
                    from r in rentals
                    select new ReducedResult
                    {
                        MovieId = r.MovieId,
                        UserRentalCounts = new[] { new UserRentalCount { UserId = r.UserId, Count = 1 } }
                    });

                AddMap<Movie>(movies =>
                    from m in movies
                    select new ReducedResult
                    {
                        MovieId = m.Id,
                        UserRentalCounts = new[] { new UserRentalCount { UserId = null, Count = 0 } }
                    });

                Reduce = results =>
                    from result in results
                    group result by result.MovieId
                    into g
                    select new
                    {
                        MovieId = g.Key,
                        UserRentalCounts = (
                                from userRentalCount in g.SelectMany(x => x.UserRentalCounts)
                                group userRentalCount by userRentalCount.UserId
                                into subGroup
                                select new UserRentalCount { UserId = subGroup.Key, Count = subGroup.Sum(b => b.Count) })
                            .ToArray()
                    };
            }

            public class ReducedResult
            {
                public string MovieId { get; set; }
                public UserRentalCount[] UserRentalCounts { get; set; }
            }

            public class UserRentalCount
            {
                public string UserId { get; set; }
                public int Count { get; set; }
            }
        }

        public class User
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }

        public class Movie
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }

        public class MovieRental
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string MovieId { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your requirement says "for a given user", if you really are looking only for a single user, you can do this with a Multi-Map index. Use the Movies table itself to produce the baseline zero-count records and then map in the actual MovieRentals records for the user on top of that.

If you really need it for all users crossed with all movies, I don't believe there is a way to do this cleanly with RavenDB as this would be considered [reporting which is noted as one of the sour spots for RavenDB](https://ayende.com/blog/136197/when-should-you-not-use-ravendb).

Here are some options if you really want to try to do this with RavenDB:

1) Create dummy records in the DB for every user and every movie and use those in your index with a 0 count. Whenever a movie or user is added/updated/deleted, update the dummy records accordingly.

2) Generate the zero-count records yourself in memory on request and merge that data with the data that RavenDB gives you back for the non-zero counts. Query for all users, query for all movies, create the baseline zero-count records, then do the actual query for non-zero counts and layer that on top. Finally, apply paging/filtering/sorting logic.

3) Use the SQL replication bundle to replicate the Users, Movies, and MovieRental tables out to SQL and use SQL for this "reporting" query.

Comment: Thanks for this, David. I don't like option 2, because when having to sort by the count, I would need to load "everything" in memory when also considering paging. Option 3 is definitely the way to go, and I realize, the limitation to aggregating and such is the trade-off when choosing RavenDB. In this particular situation, while waiting for answers, I ended up keeping the "favourite movies" list separate from the "all movies" list (thus a simple index on `MovieRentals` with grouping and sum) - it even turned out to be better UX for the end-user imo. Thanks again and here's your bounty :)